# How to increase Checkbutton size - Tkinter

Tags: python, button, checkbox, tkinter

Is it possible to enlarge the tiny check box of the Checkbutton object? The size is out of proportion when increasing the text size. I searched through the following link ([Checkbutton](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/checkbutton.html)) and can't find anything about the actual size of the box. Thank you for your help.

Comment: when u create a instance, change the width and height parameters. 
`checkbox = Checkbutton(frame, width=50, height=50)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to change the size of the checkbutton, but you can supply your own images. So, one solution is to create your own images at various sizes.

Comment: This answer is very useful thanks, another alternative to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

3 years late, but, now it's possible. firstly, you need to find out what type the checkbutton is. we do that in the following way:

```
# making checkbutton
option_var = tk.StringVar()

checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(text='abc', variable = option_var, onvalue'hi', offvalue='bye')

checkbutton.pack()

# checking checkbutton style
print(checkbutton.winfo.class())
```

in most cases, the checkbutton style would be 'TCheckbutton'.
all that's left is to configure it

```
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure('TCheckbutton', font = 11)
```