# Resize checkbox in Checkbutton

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I've recently started learning about Tkinter in python.

What I want is to be able to resize all elements I use in my app.
I'm using mostly Labels and Buttons, but I also use one Checkbutton.
Changing the default font size does the trick for almost all elements, except for Checkbutton.

The text of Checkbutton scales, as does the area that Checkbutton occupies.
But the checkbox (the box beside the text) doesn't change.
If it could scale depending on the font size, that would be perfect, but manually setting the size is also accaptable.

I'm using pack() for placing the components, if it changes anything.

I didn't post any code as I see no point in it, if needed I can post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46266090/12121416 (and my own research so far), there is no way to do this without creating your own checkbox.