# Saving the value of a checkbox if it's on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need help. While I'm saving the value of "box" it just writes ".!checkbutton" instead of the value I want. Why does this happen and how to fix it.
So I want it to write the onvalue in the txt instead of .!checkbutton if the box is ticked
how to fix this
Also if there is a way to make the checkbox bigger I would appreciate it :)

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os

root = Tk()
root.title('Feedback')
root.geometry("400x400")

organizerlist = [

    "213",
    "1231",
    "123",
    "123",
    "123",
    "123",
    "123",
    "."

]

eventsnames = [

    "Rocket League"
]
def run():
  # getting the name
    filename = filename_ent.get()



    if filename == '':
        # to show an error that boxes are empty
        messagebox.showerror(
            'File exists', 'File already exists, try some other name thas is not used before')
    if os.path.exists(f'{filename}.txt'):
        # to show an error if the file already exists
        messagebox.showerror(
            'File exists', 'File already exists, try some other name not used before')
    else:
        # to open the file for python
        new = open(f'{filename}.txt', '+w', encoding='utf-8')
        # to write the name and email inside the file
        new.write(f'''Admin of the event: {clicked.get()}\n{responsible.get()} \n{box}''')
        lfilename.config(text=f'The Feedback has been written successfully!')  # to change the label to the name
        os.startfile(f'{filename}.txt')  # to open the file in a new window


lfilename = Label(root,text="What do you want to call the file?", font = ("helvatica, 14"))
lfilename.grid(row=0, column=0)
filename_ent = Entry(root)
filename_ent.grid(row=1, column=0)


clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set("Who is Admin?")
drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, "User", "@User2", "@User3", "@User")      
drop.grid(row=2, column=0)





eventname = StringVar()
eventname.set("Which event was it?" )
eventname_drop = OptionMenu(root, eventname, *eventsnames, )
eventname_drop.grid(row=3,column=0, )


responsible = StringVar()
responsible.set("Who is the responsible?")
responsible_drop = OptionMenu(root, responsible, *organizerlist)
responsible_drop.grid(row=4,column=0)

responsible_drop.config(width=30, font=("helvatica", 14))

var = StringVar()
box = Checkbutton(root,text="test", variable=var, onvalue="Working", offvalue="Not Working")
box.grid(row=3,column=3)

b = Button(root, text='Done', command=run)
b.grid(row=20, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: To inspect the state of the Checkbutton, query the variable you assigned to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing function to to below:

```
def run():
  # getting the name
    filename = filename_ent.get()

    if filename == '':
        # to show an error that boxes are empty
        messagebox.showerror('Empty Box', 'Make sure to to fill the filename box.')
    elif os.path.exists(f'{filename}.txt'):
        # to show an error if the file already exists
        messagebox.showerror(
            'File exists', 'File already exists, try some other name not used before')
    else:
        # to open the file for python
        new = open(f'{filename}.txt', '+w', encoding='utf-8')
        # to write the name and email inside the file
        new.write(f'Admin of the event: {clicked.get()}\n{responsible.get()} \n{var.get()}')
        lfilename.config(text=f'The Feedback has been written successfully!')  # to change the label to the name
        os.startfile(f'{filename}.txt')  # to open the file in a new window
```

In short, you forgot to call `var.get()` and you said `box` instead, which was the checkbutton itself.

Also Ive changed your second `if` statement to `elif` because having multiple `if` will lead to the second `if` getting executed, no matter what the conditions on first `if` was. Just try saying an empty filename with your code, and you can see the problem.

Hope this helped, do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Comment: @CoolCloud Oof, your link killed my browser. Try this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46266090/12708583

Comment: @CoolCloud It also refers to answers: in short, it's considered distraction by most people and will be removed by someone else if not me.