# need larger checkbox in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating an entry screen to log data and trying my luck with python and tkinter. I am making some progress, but I cannot find a way to get the Checkbutton to be larger.  Do I have to create my own, larger, images to achieve larger boxes?  I tried using the tk.Checkbutton instead of the ttk.Checkbutton, as it looked like it had more parameters (but I might be missing something with the "style" parameter).

```
wo_issued_chk = tk.Checkbutton(self, height=3, bg=c.SCREENCOLOR).grid(row=7, column=6)
test_after_chk = tk.Checkbutton(self, bg=c.SCREENCOLOR).grid(row=7, column=7)
sample_taken_chk = tk.Checkbutton(self, bg=c.SCREENCOLOR).grid(row=7, column=8)
```

[Table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95fOL.png)
Once I resolve this, I will work on my text justification :)

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46266090/15338443), you cannot change the size of checkboxes. However, you can make an image, and use it there.